# What are some good alternatives to BUP for backing up photos?

Tags: backup, archiving

Despite regularly backing up my photos I've discovered that some of my photos are corrupted due to silent data corruption. I've not noticed the corruption until the good copies are over written by the bad copies. I've discovered BUP, which allows me to generate a parity file for fixing corrupted archives. It can be used on both of my Windows/Linux OS and allows dedup which I'm very happy of.

However, the software falls short on several areas 1) lacks ability for me to encrypt the files 2) community seems rather small so I'm worried how future proof the software will be 3) is not stand alone and needs prerequisites.

Are there any alternatives that has all the features of bup with more functionality? I'm aware that zfs filesystem has more functions but I can't read it with Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So I've [edit]ed the title of your post. You might wish to repeat the edit filling the gaps – see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Missing e.g. on what OS it must run (Win+Linux?)

Answer (score 2):

I read the features description of bup (interesting) on GitHub and *maybe* you should look into using good-ol' DAR, if I understood correctly what you need.

Actively developed software, incremental/differential backups, good encryption, data protection through redundancy (using Parchive, just as bup if I'm not mistaken), and multi OS support (with official Windows binaries): http://dar.linux.free.fr/doc/Features.html

Two issues: technically there is no dedup, and Parchive is still a separate piece of software. I found [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/dar/mailman/message/29933850/) in the sourceforge mailing lists related to dedup.